# Не работает Process.Start("url")

Tags: c#, winforms

Почему, но не могу понять почему... c# считает это за директорию.., а не ссылку:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki");
}
```

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki") { UseShellExecute = true });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В .NET Core 3.1 и новее параметр `UseShellExecute` имеет значение по умолчанию `false`. А это значит что будет прямой системный вызов на запуск исполняемого файла.

Чтобы это исправить, надо переадресовать вызов в шелл системы.

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki")
{
    UseShellExecute = true
});
```